# Output via a popup box (after the word typed in the search box)

Tags: uisearchbar

If you want to search for a audio then a popup appears, which showing you where you can find the music.

And you can enter the title in different ways (Pioik, Pioyk, Pioic)

Here is a picture to better describe my problem:
http://copticmovies.net/IMG_4157.png

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution is to have **"different mappings between related words"**
And based on that mappings fetch your data as you need.

Hope it helps.